# Determinant of $4 \times 4$ matrix using the properties of the determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I'm having some trouble with the following exercice:

> Using only the properties of the determinant, prove that:
> $$\det \left(
> \begin{matrix} 
> 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
> a & b & c & d \\
> a^2 & b^2 & c^2 & d^2 \\
> a^3 & b^3 & c^3 & d^3
> \end{matrix}
> \right) = (d − a)(d − c)(d − b)(c − b)(c − a)(b − a)$$

I know how to solve this using Laplace formula but I don't see how I can use the properties of the determinant to do this. I tried to put the matrix in it's reduced form but I'm having some trouble doing it. How can I solve this problem?

---

Edit: this is the list of properties that I'm allowed to use:

- If a matrix $A$ has two identical lines then $\det (A) = 0$
- $\det(I_n) = 1$
- Let:

$$A =\left( 
\begin{matrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & ... & a_{1n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
\alpha a'_{i1} + \beta a''_{i1} & \alpha a'_{i2} + \beta a''_{i2} & ... &\alpha a'_{in} + \beta a''_{in} \\
\vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} & ... & a_{nn}
\end{matrix}
\right)$$

If $$A' = \left( 
\begin{matrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & ... & a_{1n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
a'_{i1}& a'_{i2}& ... & a'_{in}  \\
\vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} & ... & a_{nn}
\end{matrix}
\right)$$

and $$A'' = \left( 
\begin{matrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & ... & a_{1n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
a''_{i1}& a''_{i2}& ... & a''_{in}  \\
\vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} & ... & a_{nn}
\end{matrix}
\right)$$

Then $\det(A) = \alpha \det(A') + \beta \det(A'')$

These are the properties that I'm allowed to use.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the intended solution, but a standard way of evaluating this "Vandermonde determinant" is to treat $d$ as a variable, so that the determinant is a polynomial of degree $3$ in $d$, and then gain information about that polynomial by plugging in $d=a$ and $d=b$ and $d=c$.

Comment: I don't think that's what the teacher wanted us to do, but that's very nice. I'll try that anyway, Thanks @GregMartin